# explain o/p of below macro code

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std
#define SQUARE(x) (x+1 *x+1)  // Complete the Macro defion
int main() {

    int i, j;

    cin >> i;

    j = SQUARE(i + 1); 

    cout << j << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be more polite - say "please".

Comment: What output are you expecting? If it matches your expectation, what's there to explain?

Answer (score 1):

The *preprocessor* performs substitution with macros, so, let's do the same:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define SQUARE(x) (x+1 *x+1)  // Complete the Macro defion
int main() 
{
    int i, j;
    cin >> i;
    // Substitute "i + 1" for "x" in macro:
    j = i + 1 + 1 * i + 1 + 1;
    cout << j << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is left as an exercise for the reader.
(Remember that math precedence rules apply.)

*Reminder:  macros are evil, prefer inlined functions.  For example, does `SQUARE("HELLO")` make sense?*

The macro could easily be replaced by:

```
inline int SQUARE(int x)
{
  return (x + 1) * (x + 1);
}
```

The `inline` is a suggestion to the compiler to replace the code of the function *inline* where the call is, eliminating a function call.

The above code prevents somebody from doing `SQUARE("Hello");` because compiler will flag it as an error.